# Nutch/Hadoop: regex-normalize.xml and regex-urlfilter.txt not found error even though they exist

Tags: eclipse, hadoop, nutch

I am trying to run nutch and hadoop through eclipse and followed a couple tutorials to set it up. I am currently stuck at a nullpointerexception that I believe is being caused due to regex-urlfilter.txt and regex-normalize.xml not being found.

Here is the error trace from the logs:-

```
[LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration  - regex-normalize.xml not found
4473 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] WARN org.apache.nutch.net.urlnormalizer.regex.RegexURLNormalizer  - Can't load the default rules! 
4477 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] DEBUG org.apache.nutch.util.ObjectCache  - No object cache found for conf=Configuration: core-default.xml, core-site.xml, mapred-default.xml, mapred-site.xml, yarn-default.xml, yarn-site.xml, hdfs-default.xml, hdfs-site.xml, file:/tmp/hadoop-338737067/mapred/local/localRunner/338737067/job_local1524701719_0001/job_local1524701719_0001.xml, instantiating a new object cache
4486 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration  - regex-urlfilter.txt not found
4486 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask  - Starting flush of map output
4516 [LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0] DEBUG org.apache.hadoop.util.concurrent.ExecutorHelper  - afterExecute in thread: LocalJobRunner Map Task Executor #0, runnable type: java.util.concurrent.FutureTask
4516 [Thread-3] INFO org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner  - map task executor complete.
4521 [Thread-3] WARN org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner  - job_local1524701719_0001
java.lang.Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.runTasks(LocalJobRunner.java:491)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:551)
```

Both these files exist in \workspace\apache-nutch-1.16\conf folder and I am not sure what I am doing wrong. I have double checked that my environment variables are set correctly for HADOOP_HOME and HADOOP_BIN and they are pointing to the right directories. I am not sure which directory they are looking into to find regex-urlfilter.txt and regex-normalize.xml. Any help in resolving this issue would be appreciated.

I am using Hadoop 3.0.0 and apache-nutch-1.16.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `conf/` folder needs to be on the Java classpath. This is easiest done by running Nutch using one of the provided scripts `bin/nutch` or `bin/crawl`. If the binary package is used, the script location is `apache-nutch-1.16/bin/nutch`. With the source package it's `apache-nutch-1.16/runtime/local/bin/nutch` after `ant runtime` has been executed. Using the scripts also allows to have the configuration files in a different directory and point NUTCH_CONF_DIR to this directory. The scripts will just put this location in front of the classpath.

Comment: Thank you! Adding it to classpath worked.
Reference for adding: https://wiki.apache.org/confluence/display/INFRATEST001/RunNutchInEclipse0.9 for others who are looking for a solution.

Comment: Greate! That's the correct reference (more recent and maintained): https://wiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NUTCH/RunNutchInEclipse1.0

Comment: Correction: that's even better: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/NUTCH/RunNutchInEclipse